# Missing Project SubType in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a Browser Link Extension file in Visual Studio 2013. I already installed all important downloads, but I am receiving this error:

[image]

The file is showing in temp folder is changing every time I create the project. See the below image:

[image]

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio 2013 are you using?

Comment: @CodeCaster Ultimate 2013

Comment: just check the link project manager of visual studio said he will look in to it . you might to contact microsoft support http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780263/vs2012-subtype-3ac096d0-a1c2-e12c-1390-a8335801fdab-is-unsupported-by-this-installation

Answer (score 0):

have you download and installed Web Essentials 2013 ?
if not then download from it [web essentials 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361)

Comment: Yes, i have download the web essentials